# Selenium Session not created while using chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

Hi guys so I am working in an organization where network connectivity is heavily regulated and while trying to start chrome using selenium and I am facing this issue

```
eb 19, 2024 5:37:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager lambda$runCommand$1

WARNING: Exception managing chrome: Error parsing JSON from URL https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json expected value at line 1 column 1

Feb 19, 2024 5:37:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager lambda$runCommand$1

WARNING: Error sending stats to Plausible: error sending request for url (http://172.16.223.38:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=700255047): operation timed out

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer

 (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)

 (Session info: chrome=121.0.6167.185) 

Host info: host: 'CAN-0401-D8132', ip: '10.255.16.159'

Build info: version: '4.17.0', revision: 'e52b1be057*'

System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.10'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], binary: C:\Program Files\Google\Chr..., extensions: []}}]}]

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:139)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:95)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:162)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:519)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:233)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:162)

at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)

at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:89)

at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)

at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)

at Chrome_Open.main(Chrome_Open.java:22)
```

Chrome version-`121.0.6167.184`
Chrome driver same and maven repository access is not there so can anybody provide a fix for this

Tried to run chrome using selenium and chromedriver but exception occurred

Comment: Can you share the relevant code in the question?